# Drop image and release when it goes out of bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to programming in Objective-C, and am currently having an issue with the code below. I am trying to make an image drop when a button is touched, and it simply freezes when trying to do so. It needs to drop the image until it reaches the bottom of the screen, which then it should be released.

```
- (IBAction)itemDrop:(UIButton *)sender{

if (strncmp([[sender currentTitle] UTF8String], [copyPrimaryArray[0] UTF8String], 2) == 0)
{
    UIImage *bubblImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red_apple.png"];
    UIImageView *appleImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bubblImage];
    appleImg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [appleImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [appleImg sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:appleImg];

    NSLog(@"You clicked the Apple");
    int i = 0;
    CGPoint coordinates = sender.frame.origin;
    CGFloat x = coordinates.x;
    CGFloat y = coordinates.y;
    CGFloat z = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height;
    while (y < z) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    appleImg.center = CGPointMake(x, y+i);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    i++;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to move the image view one point at a time manually. That's what I seem to understand from your use of the while loop. Objective-c does a lot of things for you.

```
UIImage *bubblImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red_apple.png"];
UIImageView *appleImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bubblImage];

// Set the frame of the original position here, for example:
CGRect originalPosition = CGRectMake(0, 0, appleImg.frame.size.width, appleImg.frame.size.height);
appleImg.frame = originalPosition;

// Then animate it to the new position:
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             animations:^{
                 CGRect newPosition = CGRectMake(0, 640, appleImg.frame.size.width, appleImg.frame.size.height);
                 appleImg.frame = newPosition;
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 NSLog(@"completion block"); // You can set the completion block to nil if you have nothing to do here.
             }];
```

Make sure to start using block based animations.
The use of UIView's beginAnimations:context is highly discouraged since iOS 4.0.

Comment: No problem, that's what this site is for. I would add you can use `if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:copyPrimaryArray[0]])` instead of the C code you have in there.